# Filling in NaN values according to another Column and Row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF like so:

```
Name      Food      Year_eaten      Month_eaten

Maria     Rice        2014               3
Maria     Rice        2015              NaN
Maria     Rice        2016              NaN
Jack      Steak       2011              NaN
Jack      Steak       2012               5
Jack      Steak       2013              NaN
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Name      Food      Year_eaten      Month_eaten

Maria     Rice        2014               3
Maria     Rice        2015               3
Maria     Rice        2016               3
Jack      Steak       2011               5
Jack      Steak       2012               5
Jack      Steak       2013               5
```

I want to fill in the NaN's according to this condition:

```
If the row's Name, Food is the same and the Year's are consecutive:
     Fill the NaN's with the Month_eaten corresponding to the row that isn't a NaN
```

There will be a person that has all NaN's for the Month_eaten, but I don't need to worry about that for now. Only the one's with at least one value for the Month_eaten in any of the years.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group on "Name", "Food", and a custom column created by `diff`ing the rows of "Year_eaten".

```
u = df.Year_eaten.diff().bfill().ne(1).cumsum()
v = df.groupby(['Name','Food', v]).Month_eaten.transform('first')

df['Month_eaten'] = df.Month_eaten.fillna(v, downcast='infer')

df
    Name   Food  Year_eaten  Month_eaten
0  Maria   Rice        2014            3
1  Maria   Rice        2015            3
2  Maria   Rice        2016            3
3   Jack  Steak        2011            5
4   Jack  Steak        2012            5
5   Jack  Steak        2013            5
```

---

Another solution, if *no* group has all rows with NaN, is using `groupby` and `ffill` (everything else is the same).

```
df['Month_eaten'] = df.groupby(['Name','Food', u]).Month_eaten.ffill().bfill()
df
    Name   Food  Year_eaten  Month_eaten
0  Maria   Rice        2014            3
1  Maria   Rice        2015            3
2  Maria   Rice        2016            3
3   Jack  Steak        2011            5
4   Jack  Steak        2012            5
5   Jack  Steak        2013            5
```

Comment: look better now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `diff().ne(1).cumsum()`  create the continue year group key

```
continueyear=df.groupby(['Name','Food']).Year_eaten.apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(1).cumsum())
```

---

Then using `groupby` with `apply` `ffill` and `bfill`

```
df.groupby([df.Name,df.Food,continueyear]).Month_eaten.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill().astype(int))
Out[26]:
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    5
4    5
5    5
Name: Month_eaten, dtype: int32
```